# zipAlignDebug input file does not exist Error

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

Ever since I updated to gradle alpha 6, I've been getting this error and can't build:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:zipalignDebug'.
> File 'C:\User\...\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk' specified for property 'inputFile' does not exist.
```

I've tried all the suggestions and nothing is fixing this. Any tips? It was working on alpha 2, but now it gives me an error saying my version is too old and I need to move to a newer one. Thanks!

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nwoodthorpe.waterloohacks"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run **build** every time before Run 'app'.

Comment: Selecting "build -> build APK" in Android Studio did work for me

Comment: Try app -> Tasks -> build -> build in Gradle panel.